# submit form before following clicked link

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have a page with a few inputs, a validate button as well as some links.

I would like to have the following behaviour: when the user clicks a link, the form is submitted (data is saved) before following the link.

I tried to use jquery form.submit() on link click event, but the data isn't saved.
If I use event.preventDefault() before form.submit(), data is saved but the link isn't opened, the action link of the submit button is opened instead.

How could I do this?

Comment: Try using e.preventDefault() and then submit the form, then follow the link.  I'll provide an answer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Ajax for this functionality

```
<a href="somepage.html" class="link">Link</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.link').click(function(e){

var href = $(this).attr('href');
e.preventDefault();
//do ajax for saving the data-- refer jquery ajax

$.ajax({
      url:'your form action',
      type:'post',
      data:anydata to send
     success:funtion(msg){ //return a value ok if form saved or fail if form not saved
    if(msg == 'ok'){
    location.href = href; //just redirect
      }    
     }

});    
});   

});
```

Comment: Comment here if you want help to save form via ajax

Comment: this is what i originally ment and then had a brain fart, lol